# Run multiple update queries on R

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I'm currently learning how to use rstudio, and its rodbc package.

I've been working on a script that changes certain values for names. But I cant seem to get it to run all the lines and change the whole file in a single query.

I've tried using "+" and "%>%", but I guess SQL doesn't recognize that syntax.

```
library(RODBC)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)


## Access file conection
diag<- "bases de prueba/DIAGNOSTICO 22.MDB"
con <- RODBC::odbcConnectAccess2007(diag)


tabla<-sqlFetch(con,'tres', rownames=FALSE)

##I'd like to run these (and more instructions like this ones), in a single run.
updatequery <- paste("update tres set centro = '" ,"Centro 1", "' where centro = '1'")
               paste("update tres set centro = '" ,"Centro 2", "' where centro = '2'")
               paste("update tres set centro = '" ,"IREMI", "' where centro = '3'")

##Apply changes on to access file.
RODBC::sqlQuery(con,updatequery)
```

I'm just a beginner so any advice or tip will be useful! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code `updatequery <- paste(...)` has one string. Then you create two more strings using `paste(...)` but do not capture their return value, so they are discarded. When you call `sqlQuery`, your `updatequery` is length 1 with just your one update.

Comment: Have you tried concatenating your multiple queries into a single  `;`-separated string? For instance, `"update tres set ... ; update tres set ..."`? I don't know that it'll work (I use `DBI`/`odbc`, not `RODBC`, and I don't use the Access driver), just a thought.